# webdriverio does not support elementToBeClickable

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

It seems that 'waitForEnabled' does not work the same as Webdriver's elementToBeClickable. Could someone help with an API of it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static WebElement ElementToBeClickable(WebElement element)
 {
    try
 {
             if (element != null && element.isDisplayed() && element.isEnabled())
             {
                 return element;
             }
             else
             {
                 return null;
             }
         }
catch (StaleElementReferenceException e)
         {
             return null;
         }
 }
```

Try above method:

Answer (score -1):

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);

element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));

Comment: you can try this one

Comment: The OP is referring to WebdriverIO which is the Javascript binding for webdriver